# Create Regex to find whole word only if includes one string and excludes another

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that returns a word ONLY if it includes one string and excludes another.

For instance, if I'm looking for the word "want" and not "dontwant" it would find the words `word_want_other` but would NOT find the word `word_want_other_dontwant`.

Currently, I'm trying to get it to work with a negative lookahead (see below), but this keeps on finding the words with "default" in them.

```
.*want.*(?!dontwant).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/EO3p_7rXheyWrj8T)

Comment: You want to exclude the whole line if it has `dontwant` in it?

Comment: Correct. Exclude any line that includes `dontwant`.

Comment: If that's the case what about using `^(?:(?!dontwant).)*$` or if you still want to make sure the line includes `want` but not `dontwant` you  could possibly use the following: `^(?=.*want)(?:(?!dontwant).)*$`

Comment: That didn't quite work, but it led me to the answer, I think. I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

`(?=.*want)(?!.*dontwant).*`

It looks for any string that, after the beginning of the line contains `want` and does not contain `dontwant`, and if it meets all those, it returns the whole line.

I'm not completely sure why the original idea didn't work, as having something that DOES work I tried to go back and find something in-between. Sorry there isn't a better explanation of what was going wrong in the previous one.