# How to run the mocha test that their describe only includes a string and excludes another string?

Tags: regex, grep, mocha.js

The following line works if I want to run tests including a string `wanted_string`:

```
mocha -g "wanted_string"
```

Then on the top of that, how could I exclude a string `unwanted_string`. The mocha command `-g` [https://mochajs.org/#command-line-usage] allows regex, but I am not able to figure it out.

Something I have tried:

1. **Different Regex**

   ```
   mocha -g "(?=.*wanted_string)(?!.*unwanted_string).*"
   ```

from [Create Regex to find whole word only if includes one string and excludes another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056427/create-regex-to-find-whole-word-only-if-includes-one-string-and-excludes-another)

```
mocha -g "^(?=.*(?:wanted_string))(?:unwanted_string))"
```

2. **Mocha Command --invert**

   ```
   mocha -g "wanted_string" | mocha -i 1 -g "unwanted_string"
   ```

Comment: Lusha, did my answer not help?

Comment: @Inigo Thanks a lot for answering my question but it doesn't really solve my problem since I am not able to add codes or files.

Answer (score 1):

A Regex to to do that is *extremely* hard if not impossible (I'm pretty sure JS RegEx is not Turing Complete). The example you gave works because the test only happens at the beginning of the string.

Unless I am wrong, here are you options...

#### Rely on something else to select tests

Instead of relying on filtering by combinations of include and exclude, you could organize tests in a directory hierarchy. Then you can select tests in a specific branch of the hierarchy and use Regex to exclude some of those.

#### Use Mocha's test skipping functionality

If the ones you want to exclude are few, it takes little time to temporarily modify the test function or suite so it doesn't run:  https://danielkorn.io/post/skipping-tests-in-mochajs/,

#### Write your own Mocha Root Hook

You could write a [Mocha Root Hook](https://mochajs.org/#root-hook-plugins) that took separate include and exclude patterns from a config file or environment variable and the skip tests based on that.

Answer (score 0):

`mocha --grep "^(?=.*(?:wanted))((?! unwanted).)*$"`